# 'Pub get' has not been run - Flutter dependencies error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I tried to install all dependencies but it doesn't work.
I installed flutter SDK properly.

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in Mi Card...                             0.7s
Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image]

Comment: What does not work? Everything looks fine. Ignore it

Comment: Click on "Ignore".

Comment: I clicked Get dependencies and Upgrade dependencies.but it keeps showing me to Get dependencies and Upgrade dependencies